# cordova white screen while using jqxwidgets grid

Tags: cordova, jqxwidgets

we are  using  jqxwidgets grid in  one of our page , the app  is working fine in 4.4.2 android devices  and all ios device   but it was  not working in 4.4.4 kikat version of android, it is showing white screeen  and showing  message **Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded**
and my code is

```
 <script type="application/javascript" src="js/jqxwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/jqxwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script>
     <script type="application/javascript" src="js/jqxwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/jqxwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
   <script type="application/javascript" src="js/jqxwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
   <script type="application/javascript" src="js/jqxwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/jqxwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/jqxwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/jqxwidgets/jqxgrid.pager.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/jqxwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/jqxwidgets/jqxpanel.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="application/javascript" src="js/jqxwidgetsjqxgrid.filter"></script>-->
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/jqxwidgets/demos.js"></script>
   <!--  <script type="application/javascript" src="js/jqxwidgets/simulator.js"></script>-->
<!--    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/jqxwidgets/generatedata.js"></script>-->

     $(document).ready(function () {

                debugger;
                var screen = window.screen.availWidth;
                var data = datagrid;
                if (data != null && data != "" && data != undefined) {
                    data.sort(function (a, b) {
                        if (a.TaskID > b.TaskID)
                            return -1;
                        if (a.TaskID < b.TaskID)
                            return 1;
                        // a must be equal to b
                        return 0;
                    });

                    // window.localStorage.setItem("grid", datagrid);
                    //  data = window.localStorage.getItem("grid");
                }

                var source =
                {
                    localdata: data,
                    datatype: "array"
                };

                var cellsrenderer = function (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) {

                    return '<button>First button</button><button>Second button</button>';
                };
                var columnrenderer = function (row, column, value) {

                    return '<div style="text-align:center; margin-top: 5px; ">' + row + '</div>';
                }


                var linkrenderer_TaskName = function (row, column, value) {

                    return linkrenderName('jqxgrid', row, column, value);
                }
                function linkrenderName(jqxGridID, row, column, value) {
                    var rowdata = $('#' + jqxGridID).jqxGrid('getrowdata', row);
                    var linkName = "";
                    if (rowdata != null) {
                        //OpenModalDialog('Alerg',rowdata.ProjectID, '80%', '20%');
                        StrTaskId = rowdata.ProjectID;
                        StrTaskName = JSON.stringify(rowdata.TaskName.replace(/'/g, '"'));
                        stsTask = JSON.stringify(rowdata.Status);
                        linkName = "<a target='_blank' style='width:100%;text-align: center; margin-top:5px;'  onclick='getTaskInfo( " + rowdata.ProjectID + "," + rowdata.TaskID + "," + stsTask + "," + StrTaskName + ")'>" + '<div style="width:100% ">' + rowdata.TaskName + '</div>' + "</a>";
                    }


                    return '<div style="text-align:center; margin-top: 5px; ">' + linkName + '</div>'
                }


                var linkrenderer_TaskStatus = function (row, column, value) {

                    return linkrenderStatus('jqxgrid', row, column, value);
                }
                function linkrenderStatus(jqxGridID, row, column, value) {


                    var rowdata = $('#' + jqxGridID).jqxGrid('getrowdata', row);
                    var lnkTskStatus = "";
                    if (rowdata != null) {
                        StrTaskId = rowdata.ProjectID;
                        StrTaskName = JSON.stringify(rowdata.TaskName);
                        stsTask = JSON.stringify(rowdata.Status.replace(/'/g, '"'));
                        lnkTskStatus = "<a target='_blank'  style='width:100%;text-align: center; margin-top:5px' onclick='getTaskInfo( " + rowdata.ProjectID + "," + rowdata.TaskID + "," + stsTask + "," + StrTaskName + ")'>" + rowdata.Status + "</a>";
                    }

                    return '<div style="text-align:center; margin-top: 5px; ">' + lnkTskStatus + '</div>'
                }

                var linkrenderer_Task = function (row, column, value) {

                    return linkrender('jqxgrid', row, column, value);
                }
                function linkrender(jqxGridID, row, column, value) {


                    var rowdata = $('#' + jqxGridID).jqxGrid('getrowdata', row);
                    var Tasklink = "";
                    if (rowdata != null) {
                        //OpenModalDialog('Alerg',rowdata.ProjectID, '80%', '20%');
                        StrTaskId = rowdata.ProjectID;
                        StrTaskName = JSON.stringify(rowdata.TaskName.replace(/'/g, '"'));
                        stsTask = JSON.stringify(rowdata.Status);
                        Tasklink = "<a target='_blank' href='javascript:void(0)' style='width:100%'  onclick='getTaskInfo( " + rowdata.ProjectID + "," + rowdata.TaskID + "," + stsTask + "," + StrTaskName + ")'>" + rowdata.TaskID + "</a>";
                    }

                    return '<div style="text-align:center; margin-top: 5px; ">' + Tasklink + '</div>'
                }
             //   var theme = prepareSimulator("jqxgrid");
                var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

                $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
                {
                    width: "95%",
                    source: dataAdapter,
                    selectionmode: 'singlecell',
                    enablebrowserselection: true, //Enables to copy text from the grid.
                    enabletooltips: true,
                    autorowheight: true,
                    autoheight: true,
                    columnsheight: 40,
                    pagesize: 20,
                    pageable: true,
                    rowsheight: 34,
                    pagermode: 'simple',
                    columns: [
                      { text: 'TaskID', dataField: 'TaskID', cellsrenderer: linkrenderer_Task, width: "20%", height: "25%", cellsalign: 'center', renderer: columnrenderer },
                      { text: 'TaskName', dataField: 'TaskName', width: "50%", height: "25%", cellsrenderer: linkrenderer_TaskName, cellsalign: 'center', renderer: columnrenderer },
                      { text: 'Status', dataField: 'Status', width: "30%", height: "25%", cellsrenderer: linkrenderer_TaskStatus, cellsalign: 'center', renderer: columnrenderer }
                      //{ text: 'Quantity', dataField: 'quantity', width: "15%", cellsalign: 'right' },
                      //{ text: 'Unit Price', dataField: 'price', width: "15%", cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'c2' },
                      //{ text: 'Total', dataField: 'total', cellsalign: 'right', minwidth: "15%", cellsformat: 'c2' }
                    ]
                });
                // initSimulator("jqxgrid");
                // $('#contenttablejqxgrid').css('overflow', 'auto');
                LodingImage('Hide');
                $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('refresh');
                if (screen == 768) {
                    $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid({ pagesize: 20 });
                } else {
                    $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid({ pagesize: 8 });
                }

            });
        }
        catch (ex) {
            //  navigator.notification.alert(ex + ex.lineNumber + 'ramakrishna', '', 'Alert', 'OK');
            alert(ex);
        }
```